# ssh-keyscan does not clear localhost

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I am running `ssh-keyscan` to update my `known_hosts` file:

```
» ssh-keyscan -p 5634 -t ecdsa,dsa,rsa localhost >> .ssh/known_hosts
# localhost SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
# localhost SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
# localhost SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
```

But then:

```
» ssh localhost
The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:5634 ([127.0.0.1]:5634)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 5f:60:a2:34:0a:57:57:bc:95:b2:29:89:11:3e:46:14.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Why? I have *explicitly* updated the `ecdsa` fingerprint with `ssh-keyscan`? (and it is in the `known_hosts` file, and it has the right permissions, and there is no other entry which could cause conflicts)

(This is important for me since I have several hosts and I want to automate the installation process, which includes the ability to ssh to itself)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it is late and I have had too many issues today. This is the solution:

```
ssh-keyscan -p 5634 -t ecdsa,dsa,rsa localhost
ssh-keyscan -p 5634 -t ecdsa,dsa,rsa 127.0.0.1
```

So, just make sure you also scan `127.0.0.1`.

Note: `ssh` is using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` because of my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host localhost 127.0.0.1
     HostName       127.0.0.1
     Port           5634
     TCPKeepAlive   no
```

Note2: I hope you can excuse my sloppiness, but I have had several issues with `ssh-keyscan` (it randomly stops sometimes when given a long list of hosts to scan, without any special warning) and I thought this was another unlucky bug.